If $p_n={{t_n}\over {t_n+1}}$, then $p_n\sim t_n$ .
I want to understand this alexheinis's answer.
Summary

$\{x_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is  a sequence of positive real numbers.
$s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$.
$t_n:={{x_n}\over {s_{n-1}}}$.
Thus, we have $s_n=s_{n-1}(1+t_n)$.
Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{n}}{x_1+x_2+…+x_n}$ converges.
We want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}$ converges.
it is enough to show that $\sum t_n<\infty$
$p_n:=x_n/s_n$
$p_n={{t_n}\over {t_n+1}}$

alexheinis says that

Then $p_n\sim t_n$ (quotient has limit 1)

I don't understand this.
What I tried

$\frac{s_n}{t_n}=\frac{1}{1+t_n}$
It is sufficient that  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}t_n =0$.


He states that $t_n\to 0$ in his solution in the first set of implications.

He proves that $t_n \to 0$ on about line 4

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{n}}{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}$$
is convergent implies $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n}}{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n}}{s_n}=0.$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}{x_{n}}=\infty,$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_{n-1}}{x_{n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n-x_n}{x_{n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{s_n}{x_{n}}-1\right)
=\infty,$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}t_n =\lim_{n\to \infty}{{x_n}\over {s_{n-1}}}=0.$$
In the end
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{t_{n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+t_{n}}
=1.$$
Added: If you don't follow @alexheinis's idea, it is an easy method to prove the convergence of the series $$\sum\frac{x_n}{s_{n-1}}.$$
Proof:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{x_n}{s_{n-1}}}{\frac{x_n}{s_n}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n}{s_n-x_n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x_n}{s_n}}
=1.$$
So the convergence of $\sum\frac{x_n}{s_n}$ implies the series $\sum\frac{x_n}{s_{n-1}}$ is convergent.
